# QEMU-system-arm installation is missing sabrelite machine

Tags: arm, embedded, emulation, qemu, imx6

Goal:: "Is to emulate imx6 Quad G4 device with QEMU or any other emulation software. I have got u-boot-mx6q-4g.bin and mon_imx_minikernel.bin files from the actual working device"

I m novice to emulation world. Honestly don't know where to start.
I believe QEMU supports "imx6 Quad 4G ram devices" with **sabrelite** board but qemu version installed on host machine Ubuntu 16.04 is missing sabrelite board, did try to install qemu-user-static but still no luck.

## qemu-system-arm -M help

Supported machines list is missing **sabrelite** in my installation.

## qemu-system-arm -version

QEMU emulator version 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.32), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard

Currently my host machine is Ubuntu 16.04

$uname -a

Linux mike 4.4.0-138-generic #164-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 2 17:16:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any guidance is very much appreciated

Comment: Why would you not ensure you have the latest version of QUEMU _before_ asking the question?  It is clearly antique wth a copyright date of 2008 and probably predates your board.  How to upgrade Ubuntu:  https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-linux-18-04/  How to get latest QUEMU: https://www.qemu.org/download/

Comment: It's not quite that ancient -- 2.5 is from 2015, but there was a long period where we forgot to update the copyright dates in the version string. But it is old enough to predate the sabrelite board being added.

Comment: @Clifford thanks for the inputs OS upgrade did fix the issue.

Comment: @PeterMaydell Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## apt upgrade qemu* has not upgraded the OS.

However Sabrelite and more machine options showed up after upgrading host OS to 18.04.
In process of upgrade it upgraded the QEMU also.